# Riemann Integrable Function is Zero

Tags: riemann-integration

I am working through a Real Analysis textbook and found the following exercise.

> Let $f\,:\,[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be Riemann integrable and nonnegative. Suppose $$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=0.$$ Find $f$.

I know that this should come out to be that $f(x)=0$ logically, but how could I show this with some rigor?

Comment: Well... it's not actually true that $f(x)=0$ is the only such function.  It may be zero except at countably many discontinuities where the function is nonzero.  Usually such a problem assumes $f$ is continuous instead of merely Riemann integrable, and under that assumption, only $f(x)=0$ works.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ah, I see. I'm still not completely sure how to approach the proof for that though.

Comment: Do you know that Riemann integrable functions are discontinuous at countably many points?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, my understanding is that this is the Lebesgue Criteria.

Comment: Then I would show that if such an $f$ is continuous at $x=c$, then $f(c)=0$ (by contradiction).